# iptables dnat not work when i want to dnat to kvm vitul machine

Tags: iptables, nat, kvm

**My iptable:**

```
iptables  -t  nat  -nL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            111.44.243.23x**strong text**      tcp dpt:564 to:192.168.122.101:3306 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

My kwm is at:

```
192.168.122.101`:
```

But when I

```
telnet 111.44.243.23x 564
```

It does not work.  Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d 111.44.243.239 --dport 564 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.101:3306

Comment: iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp -d 192.168.122.101 --dport 564 -j ACCEPT

Comment: -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 564 -j ACCEPT

Comment: tree command with iptables,but still not work ,so so confused